# Divide pandas data frame into test and train based on unique ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I want to split it into two data frames,(train, and test) using the values in the id column. The split should be such that in the first data frame I have 70% of the (unique) ids and in the second data frame, I have 30% of the ids. The ids should be randomly split.

I have multiple values corresponding to one id.

The below script I was trying:

```
Training_data, Test_data = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(data, data['ID_sample'].unique(), train_size=0.30, test_size=0.70, random_state=5)
```

Comment: `data_train, data_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, stratify=data['ID_sample'])`

Comment: @pratyaysengupta Welcome to SO community, to get a help and decent answer you need to provide the minimal set of data to reproduce the environment and draw an explainable answer, please showcase some data from your data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted the issue in the following way

```
samplelist = data["ID_sample"].unique()
    training_samp, test_samp = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(samplelist, train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3, random_state=5, shuffle=True)
    
    training_data = data[data['ID_sample'].isin(training_samp)]
    test_data = data[data['ID_sample'].isin(test_samp)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sklearn expert, but I know little about it and since ages when this came into existence similar questions I see all new-comer's used to ask.

Anyway, here is how you can solve it, you can opt to import  `import train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection` and accomplish it. I have just created a random data and applied that same.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2))
>>> df
           0         1
0  -1.214487  0.455726
1  -0.898623  0.268778
2   0.262315 -0.009964
3   0.612664  0.786531
4   1.249646 -1.020366
..       ...       ...
95 -0.171218  1.083018
96  0.122685 -2.214143
97 -1.420504  0.469372
98  0.061177  0.465881
99 -0.262667 -0.406031

[100 rows x 2 columns]
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3)
```

Here is your first dataframe `train`

```
>>> train
           0         1
26 -2.651343 -0.864565
17  0.106959 -0.763388
78 -0.398269 -0.501073
25  1.452795  1.290227
47  0.158705 -1.123697
..       ...       ...
29 -1.909144 -0.732514
7   0.641331 -1.336896
43  0.769139  2.816528
59 -0.683185  0.442875
11 -0.543988 -0.183677

[70 rows x 2 columns]
```

Here its second `test` dataframe:

```
>>> test
           0         1
30 -1.562427 -1.448936
24  0.638780  1.868500
70 -0.572035  1.615093
72  0.660455 -0.331350
82  0.295644 -0.403386
22  0.942676 -0.814718
15 -0.208757 -0.112564
45  1.069752 -1.894040
18  0.600265  0.599571
93 -0.853163  1.646843
91 -1.172471 -1.488513
10  0.728550  1.637609
36 -0.040357  2.050128
4   1.249646 -1.020366
60 -0.907925 -0.290945
34  0.029384  0.452658
38  1.566204 -1.171910
33 -1.009491  0.105400
62  0.930651 -0.124938
42  0.401900 -0.472175
80  1.266980 -0.221378
95 -0.171218  1.083018
74 -0.160058 -1.383118
28  1.257940  0.604513
87 -0.136468 -0.109718
27  1.909935 -0.712136
81 -1.449828 -1.823526
61  0.176301 -0.885127
53 -0.593061  1.547997
57 -0.527212  0.781028
```

In your case, it should ideally be working as below, however, you don't need to define `train_size` if you are defining `test_size` or vice versa.

```
>>> train, test = train_test_split(data['ID_sample'], test_size=0.3)
```

OR

```
>>> train, test = train_test_split(data['ID_sample'], test_size=0.3, random_state=5)
```

OR

This returns an arraylist ...

```
>>> train, test = train_test_split(data['ID_sample'].unique(), test_size=0.30, random_state=5)
```